# Django 1.8.1 Templates in Settings.py

Tags: django, templates

I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm following the 1.8 [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/), and I can't get Django to render my edited templates. Instead, they render the default templates in the Djano libs. See the part headered "Customize the admin look and feel" in the official tutorial (link above).

### Site Structure

- testsite

  - polls
  - templates

    - admin

      - base_site.html
  - testsite

### Settings.py

All lines are as in tutorial. This is the line they suggest to edit (like this)

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Everything else is just like in the tutorial. I think I must have the directory structure confused, and that's why django can't pick up the edited template.

Comment: Where have you placed your settings.py file under?

Comment: Can you remove or rename \django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base.html to see where django searches ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem too. (Django 1.8 tutorial).
Then, in settings.py, after BASE_DIR definition, I added a print statement.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print(BASE_DIR)
```

In command line, I entered:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

to see what value has BASE_DIR. It turned out that BASE_DIR shows to one folder higher than polls.

Then, I changed the TEMPLATES definition in the settings.py as follows:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'polls', 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and it turns out I wasn't replacing the correct part in the template. I found that out by looking at [these IRC logs](http://django-irc-logs.com/2015/may/19/). Since I'm not the only making that mistake, maybe you're doing it too :-)

This is the original content of base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

I was only replacing the string "Django administration so it looked like this:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Polls Administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}
```

It turns out you need to replace the entire content of the `<a>`-tag:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Polls administration</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

I hope this solves your problem too.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the Django 1.11 tutorial, until I realized that /templates needed to be on the same level as /polls and /mysite. Are you sure your site structure is the way you say it is? It should look like this:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py
            0001_initial.py
        models.py
        static/
            polls/
                images/
                    background.gif
                style.css
        templates/
            polls/
                detail.html
                index.html
                results.html
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    templates/
        admin/
            base_site.html
```

If this does not work, have you tried changing the BASE_DIR in settings.py? You may be a level off. Revise it to this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```